# Проблема с extends Array и splice

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Есть класс extends Array, который надо очистить.

```js
class Grid extends Array {
    constructor(board){
        super();
        // условное содержимое - 
        this.push([{x:0,y:0}][{x:0,y:1}],[{x:1,y:0}][{x:1,y:1}]);
        console.log('grid constructed');
        this.ctx = board.layers.grid; //очень нужная вещь без которой ничего не работает
    }
    clear(){
        this.splice(0, this.length);
    }
}
const grid = new Grid({layers:{grid:'2d)'}});

grid.clear();// oops..
```

Что можно предпринять?

Comment: А с "условным содержимым" всё ок? Мб `this.push([{x:0,y:0}],[{x:0,y:1}],[{x:1,y:0}],[{x:1,y:1}]);` имелось в виду?

Comment: эту строчку вообще не стоило в пример добавлять) она лишняя, проблема в том что заново вызывается конструктор, когда вызываешь splice, и все переданные аргументы пропадают. а мне они нужны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, что метод `.splice` всегда вызывает конструктор "под капотом".

Можно очистить `grid` другим образом:

```
clear(){
    this.length = 0;
}
```